# How to reverse string using recursive?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, recursion, reverse

How do i turn this method into a recursive method? I'm having trouble defining the base condition and the end condition. How do i decrements or increment the end condition to meet the base condition?

```
private string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        char[] array = new char[s.Length];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            array[index++] = s[i];
        }
        return new string(array);
    }
```

using string builder

```
     private string ReverseLetter(string letter)
    {            //copy to stack           
        Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
        foreach (char ch in letter)
            stack.Push(ch);
        //read the stack into a string          
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(stack.Pop());
        }

        return sb.ToString();
      }
```

Comment: is there any reason you don't use stringbuilder?

Comment: I somehow can understand if this question is a homework or something, otherwise, recursion is not a "good" way to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is assignment i have to do. I do have a string builder method, the method i posted just easier for me to understand.

Comment: What do you know about recursion? There are only a couple of things needed: 1. a "base" case that returns a concrete value, 2. A way to take a larger problem and make it smaller (this becomes the recursive call). For example, to get the sum of a list of numbers, you could remove one number and add it to the result of a recursive call that gets the sum from the smaller list. The base case is when the list contains one item, and you just return that item.

Comment: What a silly assignment. The string is a linear data structure and tackling it with recursion is utterly wrong. Recursion works best with nested data structures. The 'correct' solution would be to reject the assignment.

Comment: @TaW: The assignment may be silly in C# because recursion is not a naturally used language construct but in a language like F#, for example, you can easily represent the algorithm in a recursive way. You need a helper function that takes a ``StringBuilder`` and the running index as additional parameters; the end condition is the running index becoming negative (counting down), and if that is not reached, you just call the recursive function again with the updated ``StringBuilder`` and the decreased index. As the question is already on hold, see my next comment for some code.

Comment: The translation back to C# becomes straightforward. Using the new expression syntax, you can get away with two (fairly long) one-liners:

    ``private static string ReverseString(string s) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s : ReverseString(s, s.Length - 1, new StringBuilder(s.Length));``

and

    ``private static string ReverseString(string s, int k, StringBuilder sb) => k < 0 ? sb.ToString() : ReverseString(s, k - 1, sb.Append(s[k]));``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use recursive method why use loop in it...?

I have write simple method which returns the reverse string using recursion.

```
public string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        if (s == null || s.Length <= 1)  // if length is less or equal 1 then also returns
            return s;

        return ReverseString(s.Substring(1)) + s[0];
    }
```

Output Example Attached:
[image]

Comment: Be careful with `s.Length == 1`. What if I provide *empty string* `""`, `null` string as a parameter?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , Yeah, must check all possible values :)